# Call php script from windows batch script and show output in CMD

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd, shell-exec

I try to execute a PHP script from a windows batch script which I start from PHP code. So first i execute `start.php` from the browser.

**start.php**

```
<?php
$webroot = getcwd();
exec($webroot."/start.bat A");
```

This should start my `start.bat` file which executes `myscript.php` with the argument `A`.

**start.bat**

```
set arg1=%1
php myscript.php %arg1%
```

**myscript.php**

```
<?php
if ($argc > 1)
{
    $param = $argv[1];
    $number = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        echo $param."_".$number.";";
        $number++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

My goal is to instruct my batch script somehow to start `myscript.php` in a command shell (CMD) so i can see the output in there, just as i would execute `myscript.php` like this from the CMD: `php myscript.php A`

Comment: Rename `start.bat`. `Start` is a internal windows command. It will run before a batch file (or any other executable) of that name. `php myscript.php %1` lacks pointless indirection.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with "php myscript.php %1 lacks pointless indirection."?

Comment: Programming code should say what you mean. Your example is indirect. The second line intention (run with first command line parameter) can't be understood without looking elsewhere. Good programming is clear. We use indirection in programming (like language files or COM object calls) but not for it's own sake but that is solves a problem. In a thousand line program your indirection may be a good choice. But not in making a 1 line program into 2. This pattern is slower and uses more memory (not that it matters in batch - but this problem pattern is all languages).

Comment: Yes im aware of this, but this is only an example.

Comment: Applying the change by @Noodles made it work for me.